# how to navigate from view using coverflow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I implemented coverflow for iphone by using openflow library http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/ , where i m assinging images from server into coverflow..it works fine but it doesnt contain method to navigate to next view.
could u guys help me out how to add a button to an image..or is there any delegate method for image click...below is the code

```
@implementation cfDemoViewController

@synthesize arX = _arX;

- (void)dealloc
{ 
[super dealloc];
[_arX release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

ar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.maiepiccreations.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/art-off-255x255.jpg",
             @"http://www.estudiogold.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Alpha-Dista-Icon-29.png",
             @"http://muraltech.com/gallery/album/thumbsm/window-pane-art.jpg",
             @"http://www.foreman.ubishops.ca/fileadmin/foreman_documents/images/exhibitions/2005-2006/time2/aboveandbelow.jpg",
             @"http://www.neo-art.co.uk/1150neo.jpg",
             @"http://flowfineart.com/images/nov07/art-bettina1.jpg",nil];

self.arX=ar;
queue=[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i < [ar count]; i++) {
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] forIndex:i];      
}
[self requestForImage:0];

[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:[ar count]];
```

}

```
 -(void)requestForImage:(NSUInteger)index{
if(index>=[self.arX count]) 
    return;
ASIHTTPRequest *req=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arX objectAtIndex:index]]];
[req setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[req setUsername:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",index]];
[req setDelegate:self];
[queue addOperation:req];   
[queue go];
```

}

```
- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
NSUInteger index=[[request username] intValue]; 
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];
img=[img cropCenterAndScaleImageToSize:CGSizeMake(225, 225)];
[(AFOpenFlowView*)self.view setImage:img forIndex:index];

[self requestForImage:index+1];
 }
```